# Autocompletion in extjs combobox

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, combobox, extjs

I am using an combobox with autocompletion. Here is my code:

```
            {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            typeAhead: true,
            id: 'search_box',
            fieldLabel: 'Search',
            store: ariadneStore,
            queryMode: 'remote',
            displayField: 'name',
            editable: true,
            forceSelection: false,
            emptyText: 'Please insert disease term',
            minChars: 3, 
            hideTrigger: true,
            selectOnFocus: false,
            width: 250,
            listeners: {
                specialkey: function(field, e){
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {                            
                        loadResultStore();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

As soon as I type in some charackters always the first suggestion gets the focus. Thats leads to that when I hit enter that first suggestion gets selected. I prefer that the focus stays in the text fild of the combobox. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `autoSelect: false` property in your config.